# React-image-crop Crops wrong part of the Image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-hooks, crop

I am using Next.Js and react-image-crop library to crop images, However the cropped (Select) part of the image is displayed in an offset. As the selected part is never rendered properly, All I am trying to do is to crop the image and get the data so that it can be saved on the server or downloaded.

[image]

This is my code (I have deleted some parts for easier readability):

```
import { UserSessionContext } from '@/components/context/UserSession';

import React, { useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import style from '../../styles/Profile.module.css'
import styles2 from '../../styles/404.module.css'
import modalStyle from '../../styles/Modal.module.css';

import Post, { PostDataProps as PostData} from '../../components/Post';
import { Comment } from '@/components/Comment';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Modal from '@/components/modal/Modal';
import ReactCrop, { Crop } from 'react-image-crop';
import "react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css";



const Profile = () => {

    const [searchOption, setPostsSearch] = useState<String>('POSTS'); 
    const userSessionData = useContext(UserSessionContext);
    const [data, setData] = useState<any>([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [isOwner, setIsOwner] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const router = useRouter();

    const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const openModal = (state: boolean) => {
        setModalIsOpen(state)

        if(!state){
            setSrc("")

        }
    }

  

    const [profilePicture, setProfilePicture] = useState<any>(); 
    const [src, setSrc] = useState<string>("");
    const [crop, setCrop] = useState<any>({
        unit: 'px',
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        x: 25,
        y: 25,
        aspect: 1 / 1,
        circularCrop: true
    });
    const [croppedImageUrl, setCroppedImageUrl] = useState<string>("");

    const handleFileChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const file = e.target.files?.[0];
        if (!file) return;
    
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event) => {
          const base64Url = event.target?.result as string;
          setSrc(base64Url);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };
    
    const handleCropChange = (crop: Crop) => {
        setCrop(crop);
    };
    
    const handleCropComplete = (crop: Crop) => {
        if (!src) return;
    
        const image = new Image();
        image.src = src;
    
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = crop.width ?? 0;
        canvas.height = crop.height ?? 0;
    
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        if (context) {
          context.drawImage(
            image,
            crop.x ?? 0,
            crop.y ?? 0,
            crop.width ?? 0,
            crop.height ?? 0,
            0,
            0,
            crop.width ?? 0,
            crop.height ?? 0
          );
    
          const croppedImageUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          setCroppedImageUrl(croppedImageUrl);
        }
      
    };
    
    console.log(croppedImageUrl)

    return (
        <>
            { modalIsOpen && 
                <Modal onCancel={() => {openModal(!modalIsOpen); setProfilePicture("")}}>
                    <div className={modalStyle.ModalHeader}>
                        <h2 className={modalStyle.ModalTitle}>Profile picture editor</h2>
                        <button className={modalStyle.CloseButton} onClick={() => {openModal(!modalIsOpen);  setProfilePicture("")}}>
                            <i className="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>                      
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className={modalStyle.ModalContent}>
                        <div>
                            <input id='imageInput' className={modalStyle.ImageInput} type={'file'} onClick={(e:any) => {
                                e.stopPropagation();
                            }} onChange={(e:any) => { handleFileChange(e); }}></input>

                            { !src &&
                                <label htmlFor='imageInput'>
                                    <div className={modalStyle.ImageContainer}>
                                        <i className="fa-solid fa-upload"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </label> 
                            } 
                            { src && 
                                <div className={modalStyle.ImageContainer}>
                                    <ReactCrop crop={crop} onComplete={handleCropComplete} onChange={handleCropChange}>
                                        <img src={src}/>
                                    </ReactCrop>
                                </div>
                               
                            }     
                            { croppedImageUrl &&

                                <div className={modalStyle.ImageContainer}>
                                    <img src={croppedImageUrl} alt="Cropped Image"/>
                                </div>
                            }              
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={modalStyle.ModalFooter}>
                        <button>Update profile picture</button>
                    </div>
                </Modal>
            }


              ....rest of the code..

   

            </div>
            
        </>
    )
}

export default Profile
```